# Create a json file from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, apache

I need to create a JSON file using the content of two arrays:

```
$titles=array("title1"..."title20")
$urls=array("http://url1.com"..."http:/url5.com");
```

with the following JSON format:

```
{resultCount = 5;
    results =[
{"title":title1, "url":http://url1.com}
{"title":title2, "url":http://url2.com}
{"title":title3, "url":http://url3.com}
{"title":title4, "url":http://url4.com}
{"title":title5, "url":http://url5.com}]
}
```

any of you knows how can I accomplish this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Create an (nested) array that exactly matches your final JSON structure and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: are  $titles and $urls the same length ?

Comment: @vodich neither the title or urls are the same lenght.

Comment: so when there is title and no url on the same place (key) should url be empty ?

Comment: What vodich asking is.. is the element count in both arrays the same?

Comment: @xelber, Yes the element count match one with the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the array with results, [`compact`](http://www.php.net/compact) and than use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

```
$resultCount = min(count($titles), count($urls));
$results = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $resultCount; $i++) {
  $results[] = array('title'=>$titles[$i], 'url'=>$urls[$i]);
}

echo json_encode(compact('resultCount', 'results'));
```

If `$titles` and `$urls` are not the same lenght it will now use the shortest of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work how you wanted it to?

```
$array_1 = array("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5");
$array_2 = array("http://url1.com", "http://url2.com", "http://url3.com", "http://url4.com", "http://url5.com");

function formatForJSON($first_array, $second_array) {

    $results = array();
    $resultCount = count($first_array);

    if ($resultCount != count($second_array)) 
        $resultCount = max(count($first_array), count($second_array));

    for ($x = 0, $y = 0; $x <= count($first_array)-1, $y <= count($second_array)-1; $x++, $y++)
        array_push($results, array('title' => $first_array[$x], 'url' => $second_array[$y]));

    return compact('resultCount', 'results');
}

echo '<pre>' . json_encode(formatForJSON($array_1, $array_2)) . '</pre>';
```

EDIT: Ahhh - Ninja'd